# Gitlab Ci error Cleaning up project directory

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

This error appeared after configuring ssl and redirects to https.

```
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root’: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
rm: cannot remove ‘/root/builds/JyJzPjq5/0/<usr>/<repo>/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE’: Permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR/
```